# Is it possible to fetch all data without using while loop in PHP

Tags: php

I have here a large table contains all the information of specific data and I'm trying to echo out all their information but not using `while loop` is that possible?

Here is what im trying to do:

Here is my query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `info` WHERE `id` = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $_GET['id']);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $id, $full_name, $phone_number, $crew_rank,$date_of_birth,$age,$telephone_number,$vessel,$place_of_birth,$religion,$joining_date,$citizenship,$civil_status,$sss_number,$joining_port,$shoe_size,$boiler_size,$ht,$wt,$last_vessel,$address,$depedent1_fullname,$depedent2_fullname,$depedent3_fullname,$dependent1_address,$dependent2_address,$dependent3_address,$dependent1_telnumber,$dependent2_telnumber,$dependent3_telnumber,$dependent1_relationship,$dependent2_relationship,$dependent3_relationship,$dependent1_dob,$dependent1_place_of_birth,$dependent2_dob,$dependent3_dob,$passport_number,$passport_date_issued,$passport_date_expiry,$sirb_number,$sirb_date_issued,$sirb_date_expiry,$src_number,$src_position,$src_date_issued,$yellow_fever_number,$yellow_fever_date_issued,$yellow_fever_date_expiry,$us_visa_number,$us_visa_type,$us_visa_date_issued,$us_visa_date_expiry,$australia_number,$australia_type,$australia_date_issued,$australian_date_expiry,$mar_license_position,$mar_license_number,$mar_license_date_issued);
```

and this is what im trying to do with the table:

```
<table border="1" style="table-layout: fixed;" align="center">
  <caption class="center">PERSONAL</caption>
  <tr>
    <th align="left">NAME: </th>
    <td colspan="3"><input type="text" name="full_name" value="<?php echo $full_name; ?>" size="37"></td>
    <th colspan="1" align="left">MOBILE: </th>
    <td><input type="text" name="phone_number" value="<?php echo $phone_number; ?>" size="11"></td>
    <th align="left">RANK: </th>
    <td><input type="text" name="crew_rank" value="<?php echo $crew_rank; ?>" size="10"></td>
  </tr>
```

NOTICE: notice the value in each table row

Thank you

Comment: try for loop for that

Comment: So presumably this only fetches one row, and you want to know how to fetch all rows.  The answer is to use a while loop of course, which leads us to the question, for what reason can't you use a while loop?

Comment: @thomasrutter if i will use `while loop` i will add `echo` and slashes `/` in every line. and this has almost a thousand line of codes

Comment: Can you try for each loop?

Comment: is that the only way?

Comment: I don't understand why it would be a problem running an echo statement 1000 times in a loop, or what you mean by adding slashes.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be afraid of using loops. You can open PHP tags, write down your code, close them, write HTML and again as many times as you want.

Check out this simple example:

```
<?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { ?>
    <input type="text" name="full_name" value="<?php echo $result['full_name']; ?>" size="37">
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: fyi, PHP has a more readable syntax when using it as a 'templating' language, as you quite correctly, point out. [PHP offers an alternative syntax for some of its control structures; namely, if, while, for, foreach, and switch...](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Comment: I, presonally, do not like this "alternative syntax" and avoid it, so it's a question of favor.